# Understanding Dean Edwards' addevent JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events, hashtable, guid, dispatch

I need help understanding this piece of code. What is the point of `handler.guid`?  Why is there  a need for a hash table?

What is the point of:

```
if ( element["on" + type])
  {
  handlers[0] = element["on" + type];
  }
```

What does the "this" refer to in `handleEvent`, the element or the the addEvent function?

```
function addEvent(element, type, handler) 
  {
  // assign each event handler a unique ID
  if (!handler.$$guid) handler.$$guid = addEvent.guid++;

  // create a hash table of event types for the element
  if (!element.events) element.events = {};

  // create a hash table of event handlers for each element/event pair
  var handlers = element.events[type];

  if (!handlers) 
    {
    handlers = element.events[type] = {};
    // store the existing event handler (if there is one)
    if (element["on" + type]) 
      {
      handlers[0] = element["on" + type];
      }
    }

  // store the event handler in the hash table
  handlers[handler.$$guid] = handler;

  // assign a global event handler to do all the work
  element["on" + type] = handleEvent;
  }

// a counter used to create unique IDs
addEvent.guid = 1;


function removeEvent(element, type, handler) 
  {
  // delete the event handler from the hash table
  if (element.events && element.events[type]) 
    {
    delete element.events[type][handler.$$guid];
    }
  }


function handleEvent(event) 
  {
  // grab the event object (IE uses a global event object)
  event = event || window.event;

  // get a reference to the hash table of event handlers
  var handlers = this.events[event.type];

  // execute each event handler
  for (var i in handlers) 
    {
    this.$$handleEvent = handlers[i];
    this.$$handleEvent(event);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `guid` is used to give each event a unique index, while the hash table is used to implement a [dynamic dispatch table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20204926/return-next-localized-date-for-countdown-timer/21744281#21744281). `this.$$handleEvent` refers to  the element in the handler mapping table.

A callback system works by storing event handlers in an array. When the underlying event is detected the dispatch system loops through the array calling the callback functions in turn.

The [jQuery Event](http://forloop.co.uk/blog/event-internals-in-jquery-part-two) object uses a similar structure.

**References**

- [A Few Words on GUIDs](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2010/11/few-words-on-guids.html)
- [When Should I Use a Dispatch Table](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=587072)
- [Delegating All of the Things With Ruby Forwardable - Words and Code](http://vaidehijoshi.github.io/blog/2015/03/31/delegating-all-of-the-things-with-ruby-forwardable/)
- [The Gang of Four is wrong and you don't understand delegation — Saturn Flyer](https://www.saturnflyer.com/blog/the-gang-of-four-is-wrong-and-you-dont-understand-delegation)
- [GUIDs and UUIDs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms924301.aspx)
- [RFC 4122: A Universally Unique IDentifier (UUID) URN Namespace](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt)