# shortcut to existentially define variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, global-variables, variable-assignment, local-variables, not-exists

To avoid clobbering existing variables, I have code like this

```
window.x = typeof x != "undefined" ? x : {}
```

Which seems like a very long winded way to define something, but necessary to avoid console errors.

I tried this out instead, and it seems to work ok. Is it ok to define a variable like this?

```
window.x=window.x||{}
```

Or even in the global scope...

```
x=this.x||{}
```

Comment: The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existentialism) might give you some hints...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use this construct:

```
window.x=window.x||{}
```

And `x` *is* defined but has a falsy value (zero, the empty string, null, NaN, undefined, and of course false) then that value will be overwritten with a new empty object. If that is acceptable to you because you are confident that `x` will either be completely undefined or already defined as an object then sure, go ahead...

Answer (score 1):

These are VERY different.

First, without checking for `typeof ... === 'undefined'` you will essentially rewrite any 'falsy' values. But that's trivial, there are more subtle nuances.

```
window.x = typeof x != "undefined" ? x : {}
```

This will assign value of some `x` (not necessary global, it may be a local `x` or `x` local to some outer function) to global `x` (`window.x`). When that 'local' x will go out of scope, its value *at the moment of assignment* will still be stored in `window.x` variable.

```
window.x = window.x || {}
```

This works with `window.x` only; even if we forget at the moment about falsy values, it still does not work the same as the first one (it doesn't even check for 'local' `x` existence).

```
x = this.x || {}
```

And this one may go completely haywire when `this` is volatile (event handlers, timeout functions, to name a few), and will not be allowed within outer functions' body in 'use strict' mode.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to avoid clobbering `console.log` specifically:

```
var console = window.console || {"log": function(){} };
```

In general, use a [dispatch table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034742/understanding-dean-edwards-addevent-javascript/13999454#13999454) if you want to avoid the default(||) or ternary(?:) operators:

```
/* Check for IE Mutation Event */
var browser = "onpropertychange" in document;

/* Map boolean values to variables */
var detect = { "true": ie_param, "false": w3_param };

/* Map string templates with escaped quotes to variables */
var w3_param = [".addEventListener","\u0022DOMAttrModified\u0022",",false"];
var ie_param = [".attachEvent","\u0022onpropertychange\u0022",""];

/* Shadow array indices with key/value pairs */
var api = {"event":0,"attribute":1,"state":2};

/* Generate DOM lookup based on boolean value and matching string template */
var result = "document.getElementsByTagName(\u0022body\u0022)[0]".concat(detect[browser][api.event], "(", detect[browser][api.attribute], ",alert", detect[browser][api.state], ")");

/* Execute generated code */ 
var lazy = Function(result);
```

> an object that optionally points to an array of elements.  The object always has the same number of key/value pairs and each array element always has the same size. Therefore, the array indices can be accessed by name or by value.

**References**

- [ECMAScript 2015, Section 19.2.1: The Function Constructor](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function-constructor)
- [JavaScript character escape sequences](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes)
- [Character Model for the World Wide Web: String Matching and Searching](http://www.w3.org/TR/charmod-norm/)
- [Archive of Interesting Code](http://www.keithschwarz.com/interesting/code/?dir=hashed-array-tree)