# Produce Java literal syntax for arbitarary object in Java

Tags: java, code-generation

I'm writing a tool to fill an arbitrary Java value object with arbitrary values, output the content in JSON, and output a list of assertions that can be pasted into a unit test.

At the core of this is:

```
 final Method getter = object.getClass().getMethod(getterName, new Class<?>[0] );
 System.out.println("assertEquals(" 
     + getter.invoke(object) 
     + ", actual." 
     + getter.getName() + 
     "());");
```

This outputs lines like:

```
 assertEquals(42, actual.getIntegerValue());
 assertEquals(foo, actual.getStringValue());
 assertEquals([B@5ae80842, actual.getByteArrayValue());
```

Note that the string value is not properly quoted, and the byte array is not a Java byte array literal. I can improve this with a method to format the object depending on its type:

```
 ... + formatAsLiteral(getter.invoke(object)) ...

 static String formatAsLiteral(Object obj) {
      if(obj instanceof String) {
          return "\"" + obj + "\"";
      } else {
          return obj.toString();
      }
 }
```

But I want to support as many standard types as is practical - including arrays and possibly collections.

Is there a better way, than to add an `if()` for every type I can think of?

Comment: Basically you want something like pythons ```repr()``` or php's ```var_export```?

Comment: Apart from using an existing (JSON) library, you would need to handle the primitive types, arrays, and some basic classes like String, Date and such. The rest can go via reflection. With the exception of container classes: `instanceOf Collection ... List/Map`.

Comment: @user23127 I looked up python `repr()`, and yes, that's what I want. Such that if Java had an `eval()`, then `object.equals(eval(repr(object))) == true`

Comment: Take a look at http://repr.sourceforge.net, doesn't output completely valid code, but I suppose with some modifications it should be possible. For byte arrays it outputs something like byte[]{1,4,2} (so it misses the new) and for maps it does not seem to work, but I suppose with some work it can be made to do what you want.

Comment: @user23127 well worth a look. Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you embed a scripting language instead of messing with strings?

Comment: Groovy has `.inspect()`

Comment: What exactly are you testing here?  Are you doing this JSON and formatting stuff just to generate tests for something else, and if so, what?

Comment: @MikeStrobel sorry, I honestly can't remember - it was 3 years ago.

Comment: @slim ugh, yet again I am thwarted by the default SO view including old questions.  Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a better way, than to add an if() for every type I can think of?

Here are a few alternatives:

- A dispatch table

> A callback system works by storing event handlers in an array. When the underlying event is detected the dispatch system loops through the array calling the callback functions in turn.

- A lexical scanner

> The Lexer class, below, streamlines the task of matching of regular-expression against the input, as well as that of producing Token objects that precisely describe the matched string and its location within the input stream.

- A parser generator

> The framework generates tree-walker classes using an extended version of the visitor design pattern which enables the implementation of actions on the nodes of the abstract syntax tree using inheritance.

**References**

- [Understanding Dean Edwards' addevent JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034742/understanding-dean-edwards-addevent-javascript/13999454#13999454)
- [A simple lexical scanner in Java](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~imaman/programs/lexer.html)
- [Open Source Parser Generators in Java](http://java-source.net/open-source/parser-generators)